# How can I change the color of header bar and address bar in the newest Chrome version on Lollipop?

Tags: android, html, google-chrome

I haven't found anything on this topic yet. I really like the ability to change the color of address bar and header color on Overview. Is there an easy way to do this?

[image: Chrome for Android] [image].

I think you need [Android 5.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Lollipop) (Lollipop) for this to work, and Chrome's *Merge Tabs and Apps* set to *On*.

Comment: As of January 2016 the Merge Tabs option is no longer needed for this to work (in Lollipop).

Comment: It's also like this for KitKat now..

Comment: @Skuld You need Merge Tabs to see the color in the "Recent apps" view, but even if you disabled "Merge Tabs and Apps", you can still see the color when viewing the website in Chrome. But I hope they fix it some day, so that the tabs list inside Chrome (shown when "Merge Tabs and Apps" is disabled) would also display the theme color instead of the dull grey.

Comment: @ADTC are you talking about when you go to switch tabs it loses the colour? If so then yeah it's not ideal but not really a big deal as it regains the colour when you click on the tab. The big thing is that the website when viewed has the correct colour :)

Comment: @Skuld, with "Merge Tabs and Apps" turned **off**, you get [this view (link)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/jbb9S.png) when you switch tabs. In this view, all tabs are just grey. It would be nice if the theme color remained in this view. Similar to how the "app-like tab" has the theme color when "Merge Tabs and Apps" is turned **on** and you open the app switcher. *(PS: Personally I hate merging because I have a lot of tabs, and then I have a lot of apps too. I want to keep them separate or I'll go crazy* `>.<` *)*

Comment: anyone found a way to set the bottom bar (The back, home, menu buttons) color. At least a dark vs light option?

Comment: For future reference this is a link to the Google Developers guidelines and should always show the latest information: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ux/browser-customization

Comment: @gman I know that's an old comment but I looked into this and it's not possible as it could be a security vulnerability.  Those buttons are always set by the user settings in the device.

Answer (score 905, accepted):

I found the solution after some searching.

You need to add a `<meta>` tag in your `<head>` containing `name="theme-color"`, with your hexadecimal code as the content value. For example:

```
<meta name="theme-color" content="#999999" />
```

If the Android device has native `dark-mode` enabled, then this `meta` tag is ignored.

> Chrome for Android does not use the color on devices with native `dark-mode` enabled.

**Source:** *[theme-color Meta Tag](https://caniuse.com/#search=theme-color)*

Comment: Thanks. Checkout also html5rocks for more info: http://updates.html5rocks.com/2014/11/Support-for-theme-color-in-Chrome-39-for-Android#disqus_thread

Comment: Is there any settings in Chrome to disable this? I can't stand the colored address bar. I just want the default color.

Comment: @James - this may not be a fix you like, but you can stop the colour change by turning off the 'Merge tabs with apps' setting.

Comment: Really? I'm using Marshmallow, with the 'Merge tabs with apps' setting turned off, but the address bar is still colored. Maybe they 'fixed the bug'.

Comment: @user711413 a recent Chrome update has enabled this for non-merged (This started working for me within the last week on Lollipop)

Comment: Is there some way to also change the header toolbar text color? It seems to automatically choose between black or white, depending on the color-choice hue, but I'd like to be able to choose the text color.

Comment: Doesn't necessarily need to be a hex color, any valid CSS color will work.

Comment: I tried with a CSS color name, and it did not worked, maybe cause I have not the latest Android? I don't know, I am just reporting it for future readers, now I am trying with an hex value.

Comment: Here's the link to [Original documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2014/11/Support-for-theme-color-in-Chrome-39-for-Android?hl=en)

Comment: Does this work for a desktop version of chrome too? If yes how do I enable this on desktop chrome?

Comment: As far as I know, desktop Chrome does not support this. But to be honest, it would be very distracting.

Comment: The note about dark-mode really helped me out. I have dark-mode enabled on my phone and my PWA would show the theme color for a brief moment and then switch it to a dark grey color. I couldn't figure out why until I found this answer.

Answer (score 557):

You actually need 3 `meta` tags to support Android, iPhone and Windows Phone

```
<!-- Chrome, Firefox OS and Opera -->
<meta name="theme-color" content="#4285f4">
<!-- Windows Phone -->
<meta name="msapplication-navbutton-color" content="#4285f4">
<!-- iOS Safari -->
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="#4285f4">
```

Comment: And what about the loading bar? As i've seen websites that makes the top bar dark and loading bar white, but i can not find the snippet analizing the code?

Comment: **Note**: according to [Apple's dev notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/iad/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html): "This meta tag has no effect unless you first specify full-screen mode as described in `apple-apple-mobile-web-app-capable`."

Comment: @YanFoto that is actually very useful info. How would one do that?

Comment: @YanFoto I don't understand, according to Apple it self the answer provided by Edoardo L'Astorina should work... Red this: https://developer.apple.com/library/iad/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html

Comment: There's another meta tag in the dev docs for the full screen @viriato

Comment: The iOS `apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style` attribute only supports `black`, `black-translucent or `default` - you cannot use a custom color.

Comment: if you use `black-translucent` it will make the top bar transparent with white text which is probably what you would be after

Comment: What does the edit add to the answer here? It's not more in-depth, just your article.

Comment: Is there some way to also change the header toolbar text color? It seems to automatically choose between black or white, depending on the color-choice hue, but I'd like to be able to choose the text color.

Comment: On Windows "msapplication-navbutton-color" Only defines the custom color of the Back and Forward buttons in the Pinned site browser window.

Answer (score 109):

For example, to set the background to your favorite/branding color:

Add the below **Meta property** to your HTML code in the **HEAD** section

```
<head>
  ...
  <meta name="theme-color" content="Your Hexadecimal Code">
  ...
</head>
```

Example

```
<head>
  ...
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#444444">
  ...
</head>
```

In the below image, I just mentioned how Chrome is taking your theme-color property:

[image]

Firefox OS, Safari, Internet Explorer and Opera Coast allow you to define colors for elements of the browser, and even the platform using meta tags.

```
<!-- Windows Phone -->
<meta name="msapplication-navbutton-color" content="#4285f4">
<!-- iOS Safari -->
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">
```

### Safari-specific styling

From the guidelines ([documents here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html)):

> **Hiding Safari User Interface Components**
>
> Set the apple-mobile-web-app-capable meta tag to yes to turn on standalone mode. For example, the following HTML displays web content using standalone mode.
>
> ```
> <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
> ```
>
> **Changing the Status Bar Appearance**
>
> You can change the appearance of the default status bar to either black or black-translucent. With black-translucent, the status bar floats on top of the full screen content, rather than pushing it down. This gives the layout more height, but obstructs the top. Here’s the code required:
>
> ```
> <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
> ```
>
> For more on status bar appearance, see *[Supported Meta Tags](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008193-SW4)*.

For example:

**Screenshot using black-translucent**

[image: Screenshot using black-translucent]

**Screenshot using black**

[image: Screenshot using black]

Answer (score 49):

From the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2014/11/Support-for-theme-color-in-Chrome-39-for-Android?hl=en):

> For example, to set the background color to orange:
>
> ```
> <meta name="theme-color" content="#db5945">
> ```
>
> In addition, Chrome will show beautiful high-res favicons when they’re provided. Chrome for Android picks the highest res icon that you provide, and we recommend providing a 192×192px PNG file. For example:
>
> ```
> <link rel="icon" sizes="192x192" href="nice-highres.png">
> ```

Comment: this is the same as the original answer, besides adding unrelated info

Comment: @igorsantos07 I just wanted to add link to the official docs. That's it

Comment: I thought that a link to documentation is exactly what was missing from the selected answer. That's what I was googling for when I ended up here. Thank you.

Comment: This is redundant

Comment: Related: *[Answers entirely copied though properly attributed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321299/)*

Answer (score 0):

Check all these steps:

1. Include `<meta name="theme-color" content="#db4b5d" />` in the HTML `<head>` tag.
2. Open Chrome mobile settings:

   - Scroll down to the *theme* option

     - Switch to the light theme.
3. Reload the page.