# How to do a colored address bar in Chrome for Android like thenextweb.com

Tags: android, html

When you are visiting thenextweb.com with an Android Chrome Browser, you will see a red address bar. Is there a trick to do this?

[image: Android Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer following site that may help you get colored address bar:
[How to change the color of header bar and address bar in newest Android Chrome version on Lollipop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26960703/how-to-change-the-color-of-header-bar-and-address-bar-in-newest-android-chrome-v)

Answer (score 4):

```
<meta name="theme-color" content="#db5945">
```

Answer (score 0):

Android introduced in-app browser webviews  called **Chrome CustomTabs**. which is similar to launching intent for web browser.

You can specify the color for addressbar while passing url .

```
private static final String EXTRA_CUSTOM_TABS_TOOLBAR_COLOR = "android.support.customtabs.extra.TOOLBAR_COLOR";
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_CUSTOM_TABS_TOOLBAR_COLOR, colorInt);
```

for more details. please read.

https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs