# How to change the TEXT color of header bar and address bar in newest Android Chrome version on Lollipop or Android M?

Tags: android, html, css, google-chrome

I know how to change the background of the header / address bar of Chrome on Android, and that question is addressed in depth [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26960703/how-to-change-the-color-of-header-bar-and-address-bar-in-newest-android-chrome-v) and in many other places...

...but how do I edit **the URL / address / text / font color of the same header / address bar** of Chrome on Android?

[image]

It seems to arbitrarily(?) choose between either black or white.

Comment: Did you find a way on changing text color please ? i think it is possible because when you load angular.io website on mobile device, you can see the text in the address bar being black and then updating to white.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: you can't.

Depending on the background color you choose, Google chrome will decide whether to render text in white or black color in order to maximize contrast / readability.

If it was allowed, someone could go around choosing the same color for the text and background (say black on black) and visually break Chrome's UI.

Here's an [article](https://material.io/design/color/text-legibility.html#text-backgrounds) from Material Design guidelines on the matter of text legibility and text backgrounds

Answer (score 0):

you can use this meta tag

meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"