# Color in top bar in mobile version of chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I am wondering how a website like changes the color of the top bar in chrome.

[image: This is a screenshot]

Here -at the top - you can see that the polyvore navigation color (black) is also set as the color from the chrome navigation(where the link is). How is this made with css? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the color of header bar and address bar in newest Android Chrome version on Lollipop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26960703/how-to-change-the-color-of-header-bar-and-address-bar-in-newest-android-chrome-v)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of that question, that question is asking for mobile devices.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Starting in version 39 of Chrome for Android on Lollipop, you’ll now
>   be able to use the `theme-color` meta tag to set the toolbar color—this
>   means no more Seattle gray toolbars! The syntax is pretty simple: add
>   a meta tag to your page’s `<head>` with the `name="theme-color"`, and set
>   the `content` to any valid CSS color.
>
> [image: Screenshot of phone showing theme-color]
>
> For example, to set the background to your favorite color or
>   HTML5Rocks orange:
>
> `<meta name="theme-color" content="#db5945">`
>
> In addition, Chrome will show beautiful high-res favicons when they’re
>   provided. Chrome for Android picks the highest res icon that you
>   provide, and we recommend providing a 192×192px PNG file. For example:
>
> `<link rel="icon" sizes="192x192" href="nice-highres.png">`
>
> Check out the theme-color here on HTML5Rocks as well as on the [Web
>   Fundamentals site](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/), and be sure to check out the [Add to home screen docs](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ui/browser-customization/) for more ways to make your site stand out.

**Source :** https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2014/11/Support-for-theme-color-in-Chrome-39-for-Android

Comment: Thanks you! Does only Chrome provide those features?

Comment: I don't think that firefox mobile do it.

Comment: Is it possible to disable this intrusive nonsense feature?

Comment: Sometime is automatic depending of website color.

Comment: I wish there was an option to overwrite the text/icon color to white in some cases. I know it's automatic to avoid white text on white background and such jokes, but white on orange would absolutely be readable.

Comment: This seems to not take effect on the new Firefox Mobile (early 2020)

Answer (score 1):

If you use something like realfavicongenerator.net to create your favicon, you also get the option to configure your theme color (it's called the switcher, and is available from lollipop up). If you want to do it by hand, just include this to your header:

```
 <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
```

Answer (score -1):

Jan_dh is right, for those who have used the realfavicongenerator.net the tag is placed in the generated file html_code.html
I was looking for it for some time as adding the tag in a snippet plugin or changing the mobile background in elementor site setting wasn't working for me.

Comment: This does not answer the question

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35809685)

Answer (score -4):

It would depend on what CSS style the top bar uses but for example if it uses the style "bar" it would look something like this in your CSS file:

```
bar {
    background-color: black;
}
```