# Is there a way using html, css, vanilla js to change the background color of mobile navigation bar background color?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: bottom navigation bar of my android phone]

Hi, i need some help. as you can see a green circle mark on the picture, that was a bottom navigation bar on android device.. am trying to change that background color. Is there any way only using html, css and vanilla js? im using chrome.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39555747/color-in-top-bar-in-mobile-version-of-chrome

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Color in top bar in mobile version of chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39555747/color-in-top-bar-in-mobile-version-of-chrome)

Comment: bottom bar guys, not the top.