# Change titles tag (tab) background color

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have simple page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
   Text
</body>
</html>
```

I need to change title (browser tab) background color.
I tried it:

```
<meta name="theme-color" content="#ef2c1a">
```

And another way:

```
 <style>
    title{
        background-color: red;
    }
</style>
```

But it doesn't work. 
What another ways are?
Please, help me to solve it, thanks

Comment: AFAIK `theme-color` only works in Chrome for Android.

Comment: oh, how can I solve it?

Comment: This problem is browser sprecific. Your command works for Android but on other devices that´s a whole new problem. I never heard of anything, I can´t imagine that there is any way to change the color in a browser on pc...

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, then you can't currently apply this to any other browser/OS combination.

Comment: As the visitor of your site, I do not _want_ you to mess with stuff like this. My UI is my UI, that is nothing for you to eff with. Your “playground” as a web site author is inside the viewport, not anywhere else.

Comment: Anyways, as i looked a bit further it looks like you even would need an extension for getting this done (current version chrome) manually. So I still can´t think of a way to achieve this automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You can't.**

Let me elaborate: [your `meta` tag is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26960703/how-to-change-the-color-of-header-bar-and-address-bar-in-newest-android-chrome-v) and should work - *on Chrome for Android*.

In other words, this is a feature specific to [only one browser for one OS](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2014/11/Support-for-theme-color-in-Chrome-39-for-Android#disqus_thread). It is not part of the standard and will therefore not work elsewhere (yet). The only *solution* is to accept the fact that this will only have an effect for some of your users.

**Edit:**  It looks as if Windows Phones support a similar feature, [`msapplication-navbutton-color`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg491732(v=vs.85).aspx#runtime) as pointed out in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33193739/3316645). Note, however, that this doesn't seem to color the tab itself, but just the *forward* and *back* buttons. And you're still out of luck otherwise, for example on desktop.