# android webview application with colored notification bar

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I created simple **Xamarin** `WebView` application which shows only my website. I have to avoid opening my website in Chrome browser.
Is there any chance to change android notification bar color based on website
`meta name="theme-color" content="#7986cb"`
 tag?

Comment: What you want is change the color of the Chrome browser address bar?

Comment: Nope, android notification bar - the place where clock, battery, wifi icons are based on meta

Comment: After you add meta name="theme-color" content="#7986cb" tag, when open your WebView your notification bar's color don't change ? You could read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26960703/how-to-change-the-color-of-header-bar-and-address-bar-in-newest-android-chrome-v);

Comment: Everything is fine in Chrome. I want to use meta in my Xamarin Android App.