# Change color of the status indicator bar of mobile

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, css, browser

I am currently curious to know how to change the background color of the status indicator bar and the search bar   inside the browser on any mobile when visiting a certain page. I did a research but I didnt find a solution for this problem. I think this maybe possible using JavaScript, but there maybe a certain pseudo-class or event in CSS as well. Please provide me with your thoughts or solutions. Thank you in advance! Here is an example of this  color change:   https://translate.google.de/m/translate (Note the change from white to blue to fit into the google translator theme)

Comment: Please, see [How to change the color of header bar and address bar in newest Android Chrome version on Lollipop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26960703/how-to-change-the-color-of-header-bar-and-address-bar-in-newest-android-chrome-v).

Comment: Thank you for that, how did I not find that? :^(

Comment: The most difficult part of any any problem is good question ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You should use meta tags:

```
<!-- Chrome, Firefox OS and Opera -->
<meta name="theme-color" content="#333333">
<!-- Windows Phone -->
<meta name="msapplication-navbutton-color" content="#333333">
<!-- iOS Safari -->
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="#333333">
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast and clear answer! Why isn't there such a clear answer in the internet?

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- Chrome, Firefox OS and Opera -->
<meta name="theme-color" content="#cccccc">
<!-- Windows Phone (microsoft) -->
<meta name="msapplication-navbutton-color" content="#cccccc">
<!-- iOS Safari (apple) -->
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="#cccccc">
```