# What browsers support the "theme-color" meta tag?

Tags: html, cross-browser, meta

According to the [HTML spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#meta-theme-color) , the `theme-color` meta tag is valid. Google has stated that [Chrome for Android supports it from v39 onwards](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2014/11/Support-for-theme-color-in-Chrome-39-for-Android), and I believe Brave for Android, Vivaldi, and Opera (even on desktop, for those last two) also support it. Is there a comprehensive list of browser support?

Comment: Samsung Internet supports `theme-color` too.

Comment: Take a look at this answer to another StackOverflow topic related question and to its comments also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33193739

Comment: Mmmm In my case, sometimes the _meta theme-color tag does not work on Google Chrome in Android. The top bar of Chrome Browser does not change the color.

Comment: also Vivaldi browser supports it : https://vivaldi.com/fr/blog/page-color-in-vivaldi/ (both desktop and mobile)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`theme-color` is supported only by Chrome mobile browsers, version 67 (May '18) onwards, all latest samsung browsers and Vivaldi browser.

None of the other major phone browsers support this.

Source: [caniuse.com - theme-color](https://caniuse.com/#search=theme-color)

On desktop, only Vivaldi browser supports it : [Vivaldi blog](https://vivaldi.com/fr/blog/page-color-in-vivaldi/)

> Note: All though Chrome mobile browser supports theme-colors, they don't work on desktop apps anymore when viewing a PWA.

Answer (score 3):

Beginning today, `theme-color` is supported in Safari 15 and above (on all Apple systems), in addition to some of the browsers above.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safari-release-notes/safari-15-beta-release-notes

Note that some browsers no longer support the tag, so be sure to check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta/name/theme-color.

Comment: Given the user activates it in his settings