# How to change address bar color on mobile browsers in Gatsby.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobile, gatsby

I would like to change address bar color for the site, which is built with Gatsby.js.

All I came up with was the modification of the "siteMetadata" section in "gatsby-config.js".
Does it make any sense?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZljq.png)

Comment: Can you provide a minimal, reproducible example please?? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the color on mobile Android using the `meta` tag `theme-color` in the `head` of your page, e.g.

```
<meta name="theme-color" content="#123456">
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/33193739/1247853 for a more in-detail discussion about other browsers.

If you are using the `gatsby-starter-blog` or the `gatsby-starter-default` you can set this meta tag in `gatsby-config.js`:

```
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-manifest`,
      options: {
        ...
        theme_color: `#123456`,
        ...
      },
```

If you are not using these starters, you can use React Helmet. Install it by following the instructions on https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/add-page-metadata/ , then place the following code somewhere that is executed on every page, e.g. in `src/components/layout.js`

```
  import { Helmet } from "react-helmet"

  return (
    <Helmet
      meta={[
        {
          name: `theme-color`,
          content: '#123456',
        },
      ]}>
   // ... rest of the page ...
   </Helmet>
 )
```