# Status bar is black with ReactJS on mobile view on iphone

Tags: css, reactjs, statusbar

[image]

I have looked up solutions and most are all about PWAs but this is a static webpage.

I have tried to add to my index.html file but still nothing. Same on Safari and Chrome

```
<meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1, viewport-fit=cover'>
```

This is what I am trying to achieve [image]

I want the color of the black bar to be the same as the webpage

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the color of header bar and address bar in newest Chrome version on Lollipop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26960703/how-to-change-the-color-of-header-bar-and-address-bar-in-newest-chrome-version-o)

Comment: @Webbanditten Sorry I have updated post now that this is a iPhone problem

Comment: The question by @Webbanditten have an answer that solves every phone situation https://stackoverflow.com/a/33193739/9119186

Comment: @Vencovsky Thought that answer was for PWAs but I also tried using the meta tags

<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,user-scalable=no,viewport-fit=cover">

still no luck

Answer (score 0):

To change color change the code in **index.html**

```
<meta name="theme-color" content="#0d436d" />
```

modify the content according to color you need.